# Elan touchpad keeps re-enabling

Tags: touchpad, elan

I want to permanently disable the Elan touchpad on my LG 15Z960 laptop and just use a mouse. I can disable it in settings but a few minutes later it is enabled again. I was able to disable it long term at one time but I believe an update is causing my current problems. Web searches show various ways of doing this like checking the box that disables the touchpad when a mouse is connected but my version (22H2) of Windows 10 Home doesn't have any of those features. Thanks

Comment: Can you disable in BIOS?  What about physically opening the laptop and disconnecting it?

Comment: In Regedit, search `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\` for *touch*, and if there is an Elan touchpad service, set Start to 4 (disabled). You might need to disable *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service*, instead.

Comment: I will try disabling in BIOS, never thought of that. I've actually replaced the touchpad so that is an option but I would like to be able to enable it if I need to. It has been a great laptop for 8 years except for the touchpad. Thanks

Comment: I did try the reg hack but there in no Elan and no Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service in the addresses you mentioned. I don't know why this laptop has none of the usually check boxes etc. for disabling the touchpad? Thanks

Comment: The Phoenix BIOS doesn't give me the option to disable the touchpad or do much of anything. Must be custom made for LG to keep the user from changing the settings.